# wikipedia.method() doesn't return anything

Tags: python, connection, timeout, wikipedia

I get the timeout error when I use any wikipedia method, is there a way I can solve it? They work 20% of the time
That's what I try to run:

```
import wikipedia

print(wikipedia.languages())
```

And what I get:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zoomee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 706, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "C:\Users\zoomee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\zoomee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 239, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\zoomee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\zoomee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\zoomee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\zoomee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\zoomee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\zoomee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 205, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\zoomee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 187, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001D0431E4A08>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Comment: Edited the info

Answer (score 1):

This package references an API so if you are not connected to the web it will not work. Also it's last update was in 2014 which means if anything has changed in the last 7 years with the API or table structure then this package may be obsolete. You should check the package documentation as well a Wikipedia's API documentation to make sure it is current.

[Wiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page)

[Wiki Package](https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/)